# MVC Prompt Query Parameter

Tags: model-view-controller, azure-active-directory, owin

I want to override Azure AD SSO login for a MVC web application. I don't want to log other applications out in the process, but require login for security purposes. I am using OAuth2.0 with OIDC via Owin for authentication.

I am trying to use the prompt=login query parameter, which should theoretically do the trick. I found a Github reference to this being recently made available in Core but cannot trace how to do it in MVC5.2

Is it possible to do it in the Application Builder? I tried adding `.WithExtraQueryParameters ("prompt=login")` to the `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` when getting the access code. No luck.

Is there another workaround if the code doesn't come out-of-the-box?

**EDIT:** `PublicClientApplication` allows `.WithPrompt(Prompt.Login)` while `ConfidentialClientApplication` does not (also does not allow `AcquireTokenInteractive`) This is a web app so it needs the confidential builder. Tested using the Public builder and it logs in successfully. But I get an ActiveX instantiation error 'not in a single-threaded apartment'(?) Strange, unless that is how the token is being delivered perhaps. I also tested by changing to multitenant in Azure and by toggling Public client on and off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Modifier `.WithExtraQueryParameters` will not help you. You need to use `.WithPrompt` instead.Please refer [article](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively#withprompt).

**Example:**

```
await PublicClientApplication
                    .AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes, null)
                    .WithAccount(CurrentUser)
                    .WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin)      // use login for your case       
                    .ExecuteAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ForceLogin`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively#withprompt) to add paramter to `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`.

> `ForceLogin`: enables the application developer to have the user prompted for credentials by the service even if this would not be needed. This can be useful if Acquiring a token fails, to let the user re-sign-in. **This is done by sending `prompt=login` to the identity provider.** Again, we've seen it used in some security focused applications where the organization governance demands that the user re-logs-in each time they access specific parts of an application.

So, use the code as below:

```
result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                  .WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin)
                  .ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: I cannot find the ForceLogin parameter in the MVC build. I suspect it is only available in .Net Core?

Comment: You need to install nuget like `Microsoft.Identity.Client`.

Comment: The App Registration setup is for 'organisation only' so I have to use the `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` (otherwise I get a thread issue). In turn that means that `AcquireTokenInteractive` is not defined. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: For `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`, it seems that do not have prompt property.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resolved this as follows:
Under Notifications in the `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` add a reference to a new task:
   `RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,`
Then add the task:

```
private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification
<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification) 
     {             
         // Forces the user to login. 
         if (notification.ProtocolMessage.Prompt == null) 
         { 
             notification.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";                 
         } 
         return Task.FromResult(0); 
     }
```

Hope that helps the next person with this issue.